# FileReader::readAsArrayBuffer, how to get length?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I try to read file into array buffer. The file seems to read correctly but the length is 'undefined'?

```js
var file_reader = new FileReader();
file_reader.onloadend = function (e) { parse_file.apply(null, [e.target.result]); };

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', 'a_blob_file.dat');
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; 
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    file_reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.response);
}
xhr.send();

function parse_file(data)
{
    console.log('length: ' + data.length);  // <== undefined?
}
```